# send form data as web service in symfony

Tags: web-services, forms, symfony1

I am making a restrictive portal to a WiFi network using symfony, and I want to send a form as web service to other sites that want to use this portal. How should I solve this? I realize I could go the SOAP/WSDL route, but since symfony is already RESTful, it seems to me I could go the RESTful route with considerably less pain and loss of performance.

Right now, I have a working form, but I've only made a casual attempt to bring the form to a remote site by using cURL. The form does not work remotely since the routing is not set up correctly (I think). Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

to call restfull service somewhere you simply call its URL and read result. Do you have any example of what exactly is not working? Does "other" service support restfull calls? :) I hope so.

Calling rest service is really as easy as opening a website with some parameters in URL. So I am wondering what should not work. You can use some simplexmlreader or such to read restful services directly if you don't have blocked access to that remote service.